# How to set X-FRAME-OPTIONS to "ALLOW-FROM"

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

How do you set/allow cross origin in AngularDart.

I have tried just to set it in the index.html, and looked for it i code?

Like:

```
.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://http://x.x.x.x/mypath"
```

I am forwarding from a domain: `subdomain.domain.com`
Thats is why I think I need to `ALLOW-FROM x.x.x.x/mypath`.
It works without `<subdomain>.domain.com` but I need the subdomain.

I get:

```
Refused to display 'http://x.x.x.x/mypath' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header

which means this is set on the server on responses, not by the client.
There is no point setting that in Angular.